# Construct List of Nested Objects From All Documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My collection looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "doc1",
    "content": [
      { "paragraph": "lorem" },
      { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "doc2",
    "content": [
      { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum dolor" },
      { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum dolor sit" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the result of my aggregation to look like this:

```
[
  { "paragraph": "lorem" },
  { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum" },
  { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum dolor" },
  { "paragraph": "lorem ipsum dolor sit" }
]
```

I am not sure which pipeline stage I should use to achieve this. I have tried looking through many resources, but I haven't encountered any example like this. From what I have learned, it seems that stages like `$facet`, `$group`, `$map`, and `$reduce` could be important, but I am not sure how to use them together for this. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you mean for `"content"` to be an array?  Currently it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, sorry just updated that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `"content"` is actually an array, here's one way to produce your desired output.

N.B.: If ordering is unimportant, or the ordering is somehow magically present anyway(?), you can drop the `"$sort"` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$content"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$content"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CDAIShT9Wrc).

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know unwind could be used like that with replaceWith. I will be using this a lot.

Comment: @BalaramBehera If you find the answer useful, accepting and upvoting will let others know too.